# $K_v(a^{1/m}) /K_v$ is unramified if only if $v(a)\equiv0 \pmod m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, valuation-theory, local-field, unramified-extension

> Let $K$ be a number field and $v$ be it's one of $K$'s non-archimedian valuation.
> Then, I would like to prove $K_v(a^{1/m})  /K_v$ is  unramified if
> only if $v(a)≡0 \pmod m$.

I know unramified extension of local field is in bijection with extensions of the residue field. Thus, the unramified extension is generated by roots of unity of order prime to the character of residue field of local field.

But I don't have tactics to judge given extension is unramified or not.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some clarifications are in order: 1) I suppose your meant to write "$v$ be *one* of it's non-archimedian valuations"; 2) What do you mean by unratified (this doesn't seem to be standard terminology); a typo for unramified (though then the last sentence is pointless)?

Comment: Maybe the expression $a^{1/m}$ means not what I think it means, because I would think $a=1, K=\mathbb Q, m=p$, and $v=v_p$ (the $p$-adic valuation) for an odd prime $p$ gives a counterexample. Please clarify.

Comment: Now posted on [mathoverflow.se]; [$K_v(a^{1/m}) /K_v$ is unramified if only if $v(a)≡0 \pmod m$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/403893).